# Generating PDF for 90K records

Tags: c#, multithreading, task-parallel-library, multitasking, parallel.foreach

Currently I am using LocalReport. Render to create PDF's for 90K records. Using normal 'for' loop, it takes around 4 hours to create PDF only. I have tried many options.

1. Tried with Parallel. Foreach with and without setting MaxDegreeOfParallelism with different values. There are 2 processors in my system. With setting MaxDegreeOfParallelism(MDP) =4, it is taking the time as normal 'for' loop. I thought increasing MDP to 40 will speed up the process. But didn't get expected results since it took 900 minutes.
2. Used

   ```
   var list=List<Thread ()>;
   foreach (var record in records) {
       var thread = new Thread (=> GeneratePDF());
       thread.Start();
       list.Add(thread);
   }
   foreach(var listThreads in thread){
       listThreads. Join();
   ```

   }

I used the code  above like that. But it ended up creating too many threads and took so longer time.

I need help in using Parallel. Foreach to speed up the process of creating PDF's for 90K records. Suggestions to change the code is also acceptable.
Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: There isn't usually much point in running more threads than you have cores. The context switches will just end up making it slower.

Comment: @Matti Thanks for the reply. What I need to change to speed up the process ?

Comment: You need a powerful machine to really make it faster.

Comment: @userrandomnumbers: Are you sure the generation is CPU bound? Did you use a profiler? If most of the time is spent waiting for a database or hard-disk to respond, using multiple threads isn't going to help.

Comment: @Sriram I am currently using 2 processors with 4 GB RAM.  If I increase the processors, will the process take less time using for loop or using Parallel.ForEach.

Comment: @Matti I didn't use profiler. But I am not calling any Database and it's purely generating PDF only.

Comment: @userrandomnumbers: Is it saving the PDF file to disk? Is it reading a template file or something off disk? Both of those are I/O. You should really use a profiler to see what is taking the time - if it's not the disk I/O then yes, getting more cores and increasing the number of threads accordingly could speed it up. Unless the I/O becomes a bottleneck again when you do that.

Comment: @Matti Yes. I am reading the data from text file and save it in DataTable. This DataTable is passed as input to rdlc to generate the PDF . The resulted PDF file will be saved into hard disk.

Comment: @Matt Since I am using 2 processors, how much count should I give for MaxDegreeOfParallelism using Parallel. ForEach.

Comment: As Matti said, there are any number of issues that could cause this to be slow. It could be the loop that generates the data table. It could be the RDLC generation of the PDF. You could be running out of memory somewhere in either of those steps and going to swap disk. Profiling is the only way you'll know for sure where the time is actually being spent. Right now, you're just throwing darts.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know any pdf generators, so I can only assume there is a lot overhead in initializing and in finalizing things. That's what I'd do:

Find an open source pdf generator.

Let it generate a few separate pieces of a pdf - header, footer, etc.

Dig the code to find where the header/footer is done and try work around them to reuse generator states without running through the entire process.

Try to stich together a pdf from stored states and a generator writing only the different parts.